# asp:DetailsView shows one object per page can show multiple

Tags: asp.net, dataview

I have the bottom Details view and it shows one detail on a single row is there any there any method that i could use do that i can show multiple detail view objects

```
<asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView1"  runat="server" Height="50px" Width="125px" 
        AutoGenerateRows="False"  EnableViewState="False" 
        DataKeyNames="questionID" DataSourceID="AllQuestions" AllowPaging="True">
        <Fields>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="SubjectName" HeaderText="SubjectName" 
                SortExpression="SubjectName" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Chapter" HeaderText="Chapter" 
                SortExpression="Chapter" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Section" HeaderText="Section" 
                SortExpression="Section" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="questionID" HeaderText="questionID" 
                InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="questionID" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="name" HeaderText="name" SortExpression="name" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="sectionID" HeaderText="sectionID" 
                SortExpression="sectionID" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="QuestionNo" HeaderText="QuestionNo" 
                SortExpression="QuestionNo" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="question" HeaderText="question" 
                SortExpression="question" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="A" HeaderText="A" SortExpression="A" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="B" HeaderText="B" SortExpression="B" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="C" HeaderText="C" SortExpression="C" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="D" HeaderText="D" SortExpression="D" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="correctAnswer" HeaderText="correctAnswer" 
                SortExpression="correctAnswer" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="explanation" HeaderText="explanation" 
                SortExpression="explanation" />
        </Fields>
    </asp:DetailsView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not that I know of.... DetailsView is meant for a single record. Use a GridView or Repeater or ListView for multiple records.

Comment: All these allow multiple record. what does a repeater do

Comment: in a grid view can i have the same layout as details view